# Geoindex for nested field?

Tags: arangodb

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "node/1717565071",
  "properties": {
    "type": "node",
    "id": 1717565071,
    "tags": {
      "amenity": "post_box",
      "operator": "P&T",
      "collection_times": "Mo-Fr 08:30, Sa 08:00"
    },
    "relations": [],
    "meta": {
      "timestamp": "2012-04-15T09:24:35Z",
      "version": 1,
      "changeset": 11307674,
      "user": "kewl",
      "uid": 317259
    }
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      6.1428674,
      49.5716325
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to run creation of geoindex for it.

I run command:

```
127.0.0.1:8529@geodb> db.lux1.ensureIndex({ type: "geo", fields: [ "coordinates" ] } )
{
  "id" : "lux1/569778",
  "type" : "geo1",
  "fields" : [
    "coordinates"
  ],
  "geoJson" : false,
  "constraint" : false,
  "unique" : false,
  "ignoreNull" : true,
  "sparse" : true,
  "isNewlyCreated" : false,
  "code" : 200
}
```

I expected some processing, but not simple output.

I tried also:

```
127.0.0.1:8529@geodb> db.lux1.ensureIndex({ type: "geo", fields: [ "geometry.coordinates" ] } )
{
  "id" : "lux1/570071",
  "type" : "geo1",
  "fields" : [
    "geometry.coordinates"
  ],
  "geoJson" : false,
  "constraint" : false,
  "unique" : false,
  "ignoreNull" : true,
  "sparse" : true,
  "isNewlyCreated" : true,
  "code" : 201
}
```

I think that I missed with `fields`.

How I can specify right key for creation index?

Answer (score 0):

Your first try is obviously wrong, because the path is wrong. ArangoDB already told you: `"isNewlyCreated" : false`.

The second try is correct, which ArangoDB also told you: `"isNewlyCreated" : true`.

So why do you think it didn't work? Just try a geo-query. If there is no geo index on your field, you get an error.

Read more on: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/index-and-search/indexing/working-with-indexes/geo-spatial-indexes/